# Open an encrypted database created in c# using SQLITE-NET and SQLITE-NET-SQLCHIPER

Tags: c#, c++, sqlite

I'm having a encrypted database file, which was created in C# by using `sqlite-net` and `sqlite-net-sqlchiper`. 
Now I want to open that encrypted database using `sqlite3` (native c-Library), which throws error `ERROR: File is not a database`.

Comment: How did you encrypt it? It sounds like you probably need to decrypt it before trying to open it.

Comment: Or provide the password in the connection string if the API supports working with encrypted databases. BTW, are you using a c++ or a c# related API?

Comment: I want one database working in  both c++ and c#